# infopath sharepoint dispform mess my code

Tags: infopath

On a SharePoint site, I have a list where I would like to change the order of some elements of my dispform.

The easiest way I found was to modify the dispform in Infopath.
And here is the ugly part :(

Ifound that infopath transforms the code completely.

Here is an example of a `<select>`

I let you admire the transformation.

**Before infopath**

```
<select class="ms-RadioText" title="Rubrique" id="ctl00_m_g_2239bf6b_dc97_4e36_8c2e_7a3ba11d46b5_ctl00_ctl05_ctl11_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice" name="ctl00$m$g_2239bf6b_dc97_4e36_8c2e_7a3ba11d46b5$ctl00$ctl05$ctl11$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$DropDownChoice">
                    <option value="" selected="selected" class=""></option>


                </select>
```

**After Infopath**

```
    <select style="direction:ltr" title="" tabindex="0" originalid="V1_I1_D16" formid="ctl00_m_g_3b6ba9b4_b0a4_4cc5_880f_f80fc78fd04a_FormControl0" viewdatanode="17" direction="ltr" wrapped="true" class="q_1ReQGgUtfDyxuuKu_0 m_1ReQGgUtfDyxuuKu_0 aj_1ReQGgUtfDyxuuKu_0 au_1ReQGgUtfDyxuuKu_0" scriptclass="DropDownList" id="ctl00_m_g_3b6ba9b4_b0a4_4cc5_880f_f80fc78fd04a_FormControl0_V1_I1_D16" onblur="return (DropDownList.OnBlur(this, event));" onfocus="return (DropDownList.OnFocus(this, event));" onchange="return (DropDownList.OnChange(this, event));">
<option value="">
</option>

</select>
```

WTF?

Have you guys had some issues with that?

Comment: I understand your frustration, but these types of questions aren't constructive. I can see potential for a good question here. Please, edit your post, remove the rant and add more information about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to go into the List Settings and change the column order and that will update the layout of the form.  If the list is using a content type, then you can adjust the column ordering of the content type to be reflective of how the form should flow.